# RxJava queue multi observables

Tags: java, android, queue, rx-java

I have many Observable methods. I want to run next after previous finishes.

#### Class A

```
public Observable<String> method1(){
    // complex stuff (10 sec)
}

public Observable<String> method2(){
    // another complex stuff (10 sec)
}
```

#### Class B

```
foo.method1().subscribe(...);
foo.method2().subscribe(...);
foo.method1().subscribe(...);
foo.method1().subscribe(...);
```

I want to run it one after another... and that hardest one: I cannot change **Class B**. I have to change **Class A** to achieve my goal. Any ideas?

I can do it in **Class B** using `flatMat(...)` or `concatMap(...)` but I cannot change **Class B**

Comment: "I want to run next after previous finishes." What do you mean by this?

Comment: Maybe I am getting things wrong here, but doesn't your requirement "translate" into something that somehow contradicts the whole RxJava Observable idea? What is the point of doing things async/out of order, when you then rely on things being done  and in order?

Comment: @GhostCat No. `method1()` and `method2()` are invoked by button click. Also, those methods are editing the same data. `method2()` could do different stuff if `method1()` do specific operation (database changed)

Comment: Though the context is not very clear about this requirement, isn't it simple to create new methods that does exactly what you want in preferred sequence and invoke them through method1, method2 etc? I am not able to comprehend if method1 and method2 are invoked by button clicks, how and why would we want method1 to be executed followed by method2 when someone clicks on button2

Comment: Eg. method1() -> get one page of information from server - insert into database. method2() -> show all information on screen. If we do it one by one then: getFirstPage -> showThisPage -> getSecPage -> getThirdPage. As you can see If user click on first button 3rd times, than I will ask for first page 3rd times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks terrible but should do the job. Sempahore will assure that only one thread is working on data. Please notice that this solution doesn't guarantee order of operations.

```
public class  A {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public Observable<String> method1() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            // complex stuff (10 sec)
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Observable<String> method2() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            // another complex stuff (10 sec)
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```